# Convert complex Objects to Json || Serialize Objects

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I need to locally serialize an Object. What is the best way to do this?

I thought the best solution would be to convert my object into a json, the encode this json to a string and serialize this string with shared preferences.

The problem is, there is no `toJson()` method (as far as I know), that converts the whole object to a json. So I need to create this method myself. However my Object is quite complex with nested Objects and List of Objects and some attributes can be null at times. So a `toJson()` method would me very complex and cumbersome. It might look something like this just even more complex:

Workout class I want to convert to json:

```
class Workout {
  String id;
  String name;
  Routine routine;
  List<Exercise> exercises;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'name': name,
    'exercises': [
      exercises.map((Exercise exercise) {
        print(exercise.toJson());
        return exercise.toJson();
      }).toString(),
    ],
  };
}
```

Exercise Class:

```
class Exercise {
  String id;
  String presetId;
  Timings timings;
  String progression;

  Preset preset;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    id != null ? 'id': id : '',
    'presetId': presetId,
    progression != null ? 'progression': progression : '',
    timings == null ? '' : 'timings': timings.toJson(),
  };

}
```

Timings Class:

```
class Timings {
  int holdDown;
  int positives;
  int hold;
  int negatives;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'holdDown': holdDown,
    'positives': positives,
    'hold': hold,
    'negatives': negatives
  };
}
```

And the Object might even get bigger and I still need to create functions `fromJson()`. Also the conditional satements don't work well because there seems to be a conflict between ":" of the statement ":" and the actual json...

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you read [this](https://flutter.io/docs/development/data-and-backend/json) article? Specifically the part about *Serializing JSON using code generation libraries*

Comment: @shadowsheep thanks, `json_serializable` seems the best solution. A little annoying to set it up but none the less very useful!